# Storyboard : change spacing relative to view height

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, constraints

I have two `UIView` contained in a `UIView`. These to subviews have vertical margin constraints. Their height are constant.

I would like my margins disappear totally if both height constraints are equal to 0.

If one of my height is equal to 0 I would like to keep just the second subview's vertical spacing.

How can I do that ?

[image]
*Normal setup. Vertical spacing is good and height are different from 0*

[image]
*Height are equal to 0. But I still have vertical spacing constraints. My container view should have a 0 height too*

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to change the constraints programmatically. Create an `IBOutlet` for each constraint, and wire them up. From there, you can set an observer (using the `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` method) for the height of each constraint, and change the vertical spacing constraints appropriately if one or both heights are equal to 0 (you can do this by overriding the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` method in the view controller that is handling these views).

Don't forget to remove the observers in one of the cleanup methods (`deinit` if in Swift, or `dealloc` in ObjC, are your best bets) for the view controller.

Comment: This is very inefficient, and could negatively effect the fame rate if you are doing calculations every time the view is drawn.

Comment: Agreed, and this solution isn't scalable I think

Answer (score 0):

You can give the margins a equal height constraint equal to their superview, but make the multiplier less than 1.0. The two other views would just pin all sides to their parent and the margin views. You can do it all in IB and it will work.

Comment: Tried your solution. If I have a superview height of 100 I should give each margin constraint a constant value of 100 and then give them a multiplier of (real constraint value : height) ?

Comment: No you need to give them equal height constraints to their superview.